# Azure AD B2C Unified sign-up page with IdP selections and signup form

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am currently creating a signup page using custom policies.
I was wondering if it is possible to have a sign up page with the social idp selection (Facebook, Linkedin) and below the sign-up form instead of the SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At this time it is not possible to embed the sign-up experience in the same screen as the identity provider selection buttons.**

You should request this feature in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://aka.ms/aadb2cuv).

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, I will request a feature in the forum

Comment: @AngelinaSouy, can you upvote the answer and flag the question as answered?