# Azure AD B2C CombinedSignInAndSignUp with social IDP section on sign-up page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am currently creating sign-up(CombinedSignInAndSignUp) page using custom policies. I was wondering if it is possible to have a sign-up page with the social IDP selection (Facebook, Linkedin) and SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange button.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ***Social IDP*** you are selecting, you have to create different ***technical profiles*** for each.

**Technical profiles** are the mechanisms that are used to interact with the party (Facebook/LinkedIn) defined within **`ClaimsProvider`** definition whereas **ClaimsProvider** defines a party that the custom policy interacts with.

##### To configure **[LinkedIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-linkedin?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)** as an identity provider:

- In the extension file of your policy, define a LinkedIn account as a claims provider by adding it to the **ClaimsProviders** element.
- Open the *SocialAndLocalAccounts/**TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml*** file in your editor and find ClaimsProviders element
- If **ClaimsProviders** element does not exist, add it under the root element
- [Add a new ClaimsProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-linkedin?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-linkedin-as-an-identity-provider-1)
- Replace the value of **client_id** with the client ID of the LinkedIn application and Save.

##### To configure [Facebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-facebook?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) as an identity provider:

In the SocialAndLocalAccounts/***TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file,*** replace the value of `client_id` with the Facebook application ID:

```cs
<TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
<Metadata>
<!--Replace the value of client_id in this technical profile with the Facebook app ID"-->
<Item Key="client_id">00000000000000</Item>
```

Please find below links if they are helpful,

**References:**

[Ref1](https://azure-ad-b2c.github.io/azureadb2ccommunity.io/docs/custom-policy-code-walkthrough/)
[Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64215531/how-to-add-social-identity-provider-buttons-to-selfasserted-html-page-in-azure-b), [Ref3](https://medium.com/neudesic-innovation/sign-up-or-sign-in-users-with-azure-ad-b2c-part-1-29f8c290b6e7), [Ref4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857864/azure-ad-b2c-unified-sign-up-page-with-idp-selections-and-signup-form?rq=1)